# Nested riddles with triple-doubles

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> > Appears on the ice under big heavy strain.
> > Now, get off your high one, ride out to the plain.
> > It's opposite base, or with battery, rain.
>
> What am I?
>
> > It's two times what equals twelve, equation fixed.
> > With theory, G; gawking with one letter nixed.
> > Device or equipment, or nutriments mixed.
>
> What am I?
>
> > The westernmost part of a tropical isle.
> > A Johnson who scored triple-doubles with style.
> > When Barbie comes home, Ken greets her with a smile.
>
> What am I?

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Appears on the ice under big heavy strain.
Now, get off your high one, ride out to the plain.
It's opposite base, or with battery, rain.
```

> Crack, horse, acid: probably DRUG or DRUGS.

```
It's two times what equals twelve, equation fixed.
With theory, G; gawking with one letter nixed.
Device or equipment, or nutriments mixed.
```

> Six, string, instrument: probably GUITAR.

```
The westernmost part of a tropical isle.
A Johnson who scored triple-doubles with style.
When Barbie comes home, Ken greets her with a smile.
```

> Haiti?, Earvin/Magic, ?: ? (I'm wondering whether there's some homophony going on here and it should be parsed as "eighty magic X". Searching the internet for "eighty magic dolls" didn't immediately turn up anything interesting, though.) [EDITED to add:] Duh, SteveV points out in comments that Haiti+magic+doll is surely VOODOO.

Whole thing:

> Drug, guitar, voodoo: SteveV's comment pointing out VOODOO suggests Jimi Hendrix (who was a guitarist, took drugs, and wrote a song with "Voodoo" in its title). Seems plausible, though I can't shake the feeling that he's unlikely to be the only person with those properties.

Comment: Could the third one be: rot13(Unvgv, Zntvp, qbyy = Ibbqbb?  Naq gura nyy guerr cbvagvat gb fbzrbar yvxr Wvzv Uraqevk?)

Comment: Welp, the first bit is obvious in hindsight; must be right. Not so sure about the second.

Comment: At least your answer to the second stanza begins with G, so it might just fit. $(+1)$ :P

Comment: Yup, all correct! This is the intended answer.

Comment: @user477343 In case it wasn't clear, it was the second bit _of Steve's suggestion_ that I wasn't sure about. Anyway, it turned out to be right. Well done and thank you, Steve!

Comment: Oh woops. Well, your answer was correct anyway, so it deserved my upvote :D